# Change line based on string

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I would like the output to be to be changed as below.

- The line that contains `(GROUP  ) R` should have sg starting off the line and replace the `(GROUP ) R` with `props(USERLIST)`
- The line that contains `(USER   ) R` should have su starting off the line and remove the `(USER ) R` from the end of the line.

**file1.txt**

```
host server1  
    group1        (GROUP  ) R  
    group2        (GROUP  ) R  
    group3        (GROUP  ) R  
    group4        (GROUP  ) R  
    user1         (USER   ) R  
    user2         (USER   ) R  
host server2  
    group5        (GROUP  ) R  
    group6        (GROUP  ) R  
    group7        (GROUP  ) R  
    user3         (USER   ) R  
    user4         (USER   ) R  
host server3  
    group8        (GROUP  ) R  
    group9        (GROUP  ) R  
    user5         (USER   ) R  
    user6         (USER   ) R
```

---

**Expected Output**

```
host server1  
sg group1 props(USERLIST)  
sg group2 props(USERLIST)  
sg group3 props(USERLIST)  
sg group4 props(USERLIST)  
su user1  
su user2  
host server2  
sg group5 props(USERLIST)  
sg group6 props(USERLIST)  
sg group7 props(USERLIST)  
su user3  
su user4  
host server3  
sg group8 props(USERLIST)  
sg group9 props(USERLIST)  
su user5  
su user6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **AWK**:

```
 awk '{if( $2 == "(GROUP" ) {print "sg "$1" props(USERLIST)"} else if ( $2 == "(USER"  )  {print "su "$1} else print $0}' file1.txt
```

With **SED**:

```
 sed -i '/GROUP/ s/.*\(group[0-9]\).*/sg \1 props(USERLIST)/g;/USER/ s/.*\(user[0-9]\).*/su \1/g' file1.txt
```

Comment: Awesome so much Siva the awk one worked. With the sed I got error "sed: illegal option -- i". thanks again.

Comment: The inplace `i` option is a feature of gnu's sed. You will need to redirect the output to a temporary file with option `-e`

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e '/(GROUP  ) R/{s//props(USERLIST)/; s/^/sg /;}' \
    -e '/(USER   ) R/{s///;                s/^/su /;}' \
    -e 's/[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*/ /g' file >newfile
```

This is a `sed` command with three `sed` expressions.

1. For lines containing `(GROUP  ) R`: replace that string with `props(USERLIST)` and insert `sg` at the start of the line.
2. For lines containing `(USER   ) R`: remove that string and insert `su` at the start of the line.
3. Replace multiple consecutive whitespace characters with a single space on all lines.

The result is written to `newfile` and for the given input, the output will be

```
host server1
sg group1 props(USERLIST)
sg group2 props(USERLIST)
sg group3 props(USERLIST)
sg group4 props(USERLIST)
su user1
su user2
host server2
sg group5 props(USERLIST)
sg group6 props(USERLIST)
sg group7 props(USERLIST)
su user3
su user4
host server3
sg group8 props(USERLIST)
sg group9 props(USERLIST)
su user5
su user6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/(GROUP[ \t]\+)[ \t]R/s/^.*\(group[[:digit:]]*\).*/sg \1 props(USERLIST)/;/(USER[ \t]\+)[ \t]R/s/.*\(user[[:digit:]]*\).*/su \1/' file1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to @SivaPrasath's solution, but matching the whole `(GROUP/USER  ) R`

```
awk '/\(GROUP\s*\) R/ { printf "sg %s props(USERLIST)\n",$1; };
     /\(USER\s*\) R/  { printf "su %s\n",$1 }' file1.txt
```